# How to change font style in textview from cursor point onwards, not entire textview - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, textview

I'm working on a barebones text editor, and I've run into an issue. I have two buttons at the top of the app: Bold and Italic. While I have already figured out how to make these buttons alter the text being entered into the textview, they change everything written in the view, including things already written. So hitting "Italic" will italicize *everything* in the view. I'm wanting more along the lines of "I'm hitting italicize -- *oh cool now I'm writing in italics. Now I'm hitting it again--* and it's normal again."

I know this issue is stemming from the buttons changing the font the whole view is using, I just can't figure out the correct way to be doing this.

Here's my code so far:

```
@IBAction func italicizeHit(_ sender: Any) {
        if isItalics == false {
            textView.font = UIFont.italicSystemFont(ofSize: 15)}
        else{
            isItalics == false;
            textView.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
        }
    }
```

I also can't quite figure out what to set the textView.font to in order to return it to its normal state, but that's a more secondary problem. I'm mostly interested in correctly toggling italicize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that `textView.font` sets all of the textView's text to that property.

In order to achieve multiple styles, you're going to need to use a NSAttributedString (which can store bold, italic, and regular text all in the same string) rather than just a plain String.

The good news, a textView can easily take a `NSAttributedString` instead of a regular String. In order to change properties, use the `typingAttributes` property of the textView. This will change the style of any new text typed and not the entire textView. Here's an example:

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let textView: UITextView  // initialize textView either via storyboard or code
    let attributesBold = [NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .bold)]
    let attributesNormal = [NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .regular)]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        textView.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "")
        textView.typingAttributes = attributesNormal
    }

    @IBAction func boldTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        textView.typingAttributes = attributesBold
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked!
I just want to add for any future people coming across this same issue: if it throws an error at you about initializers, connect the textview as an outlet instead of directly via code and it'll work like a charm!

Comment: Yes - I added the textView there because I didn't know if you initialized it via storyboard or by code, so placed it as an instance variable for code clarity. If this helped you, please don't hesitate to upvote as well.